# Proper implementation of using a idempotency key with another service like stripe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

What is the proper way to handle idempotency in a rails application?
I am using devise and need to make sure that each user doesn't get multiple duplicate PaymentIntents for the same purchase.

Since the idempotency key needs to be used with each subsequent failed request should it be something saved in the database, session, etc..?

Stripe suggests to use idempotency keys to prevent duplicate PaymentIntents for the same purchase: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents#best-practices

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need to generate/save idempotency keys on your end. [Stripe libraries](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ruby#configuring-automatic-retries) can automatically generate idempotency keys and retry requests with an exponential backoff.

It is important to note that Idempotency keys are useful for preventing double charges in cases of poor network conditions only. They allow for safely retrying requests without accidentally performing the same operation twice. This is useful when an API call is disrupted in transit and you do not receive a response. For example, if a request to create a charge does not respond due to a network connection error, the request can be retried with the same idempotency key to guarantee that no more than one charge is created.

Idempotency keys do not prevent double charges which occur due to a button being pressed twice e.g. maybe a user clicked the button twice while a page was loading and it leads to making two API requests. You would want to use approaches like the [disabled HTML attribute](http://%20https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/disabled) to prevent such occurrences.

Comment: In addition to client side approaches you can also throttle requests with [Rack-attack](https://github.com/rack/rack-attack) or on a higher layer (NGinX, Apache, etc).

Comment: This is not what i've been seeing from stripe's docs: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents#best-practices on the third paragraph they say it that idempotency should be used.

Comment: you should use idempotency keys. You don't need to generate or save these keys yourself because Stripe does that for you if you use their SDK

Comment: That is what i though but stripe recommends to use them

Answer (score 0):

an `idempotency key` is any `id` that helps you and stripe from creating duplicate work.

For example when your user starts to make a `Purchase` in your application, you want to use the `purchase.id` as your idempotency key.

Then you would pass that key to stripe for every `PurchaseIntent` request.

If the customer updates something on the purchase, you would then pass that data along to stripe with the same `purchase.id`

Once that purchase is complete, you would keep some more data like `completed_at:datetime` and `completed_transaction_data:json`

Comment: I'm not sure if this is correct.

"Subsequent requests with the same key return the same result, including 500 errors." [https://stripe.com/docs/api/idempotent_requests]

If you encountered an error creating the intent when using the ID as the idempotency key, that error would be returned again for subsequent requests with that ID key. This might be an error due to user input, which could be a declined transaction if the intent is confirmed immediately. In that scenario I think you'd need to have a new key in order to submit different payment credentials.